# $http.get Not Showing Up on Page

Tags: json, angularjs

I've got a JSON file called `faces.json`:

```
[ {
    "name" : "Name One"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Name Two"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Name Three"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Name Four"
  }
]
```

And I'm trying to do a GET request in AngularJS by giving my main controller a `http` dependency, and putting my `.get` request inside of the controller.

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('faces.json');
})
```

For some reason, I can't see the `faces.json` file appear in Chrome's dev tools under Network. Am I doing something wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure `$http.get()` is actually being executed? Check that the file containing this controller definition is loaded.

Comment: You can also use the JavaScript debugging tools in your browser to put a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: Put a `plunkr` or `jsfiddle` together to to show the problem, if you still experiencing it. You are more likely to get help this way.

Comment: here http://plnkr.co/edit/YpWBRKwBXY21JtwZqWpn i write a little test and it works in chrome as expected and faces.json appears in dev tools

Comment: @alecxe I'm not sure if `$http.get()` is being executed. The `index.html` which contains this controller in the body with `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` is loading fine, and Angular works on this page. Just can't seem to get that `faces.json` file to load.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. You have must use ng-app in html tag.

Visit click here :plnkr.co/edit/NsMvWdPAJVxNPB2ZlI68?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the returned promise. From the Angular documentation

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
 success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   // this callback will be called asynchronously
   // when the response is available
 }).
 error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   // called asynchronously if an error occurs
   // or server returns response with an error status.
 });
```

So your code could look something like:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('faces.json').
       success(function(data){
          $scope.faces = data;
       }
})
```

You can have more code to handle errors etc, but this is the simplest implementation.